# Complex variable declaration and initialization of variables in Typescript

Tags: typescript

What does

```
 private _someVar: (value: any) => void = () => {};
```

mean?

I think it's "a variable with type as a function that can take any value and return type `void`" , but what's the deal with `= () => {};`?

Is it the declaration of variable, like assigning an empty function to it?

If so, why would someone do that?

Can you please provide me some real life example to do so?

Also, it would be really helpful to have few more such examples to make me more comfortable with such declarations.

Comment: () => {} is a function that doesn't do anything. It's the initial value of the variable.

Comment: A use case: a property that specifies an event handler. By default, nothing happens when the event occurs; but it could if the consumer of the class sets one.

Comment: You guessed what it does correctly. I can't answer why they need an empty function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It's a function that takes an `any` and returns `void`.

The `= () => {}` is a default value, assigning an empty function to it, so that if it is not overwritten, it can still be called but it won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, but what could be the place we need such function ?

Comment: You could use it to set a callback, for example. The usage does seem a bit weird. The only reason I can think of to do it this way is so that you don't have to check if the function is set before calling it. For insight into why the author implemented it this way, you would have to ask the author.

Answer (score 0):

This is an arrow function. Arrow functions are a short syntax, introduced by ECMAscript 6, that can be used similarly to the way you would use function expressions. In other words, you can often use them in place of expressions like 
function (parameters1 , parameter 2,....) {syntax......} .but in  arrow function you can write (parameter1, parameter2 ,...) =>
(syntax)